# Python - String with timestamp changing

Tags: python, python-2.7, timestamp, python-import, nose

I'm attempting to initialize a string variable in Python using the datetime package.  I expect that string to stay the same once it's been initialized, but for some strange reason (at least strange to me), it's changing.

Essentially, when I attempt:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y.%I_%M_%S_%p')
base_directory = "C:\\Users\\Ben\\report_" + timestamp + "\\"
print base_directory #prints C:\Users\Ben\report_02-13-2015_02_02_24_PM
time.sleep(5)
logs_directory = base_directory + "logs\\"
```

When I go back to use the logs_directory variable, I expect it to be

```
C:\Users\Ben\report_02-13-2015_02_02_24_PM\logs\
```

However, instead it is:

```
C:\Users\Ben\report_02-13-2015_02_02_29_PM\logs\ #!!!
```

It's as if when I access the logs directory variable, it's going back and reevaluating the base_directory variable again, instead of retrieving the value base_directory has already been set to.  Is this intended functionality in Python?  I don't it is since I can't seem to trigger this issue from the IDLE shell - it's only occurring when I run my Python program from pydev.  However, if this is intended functionality, how do I rewrite my code to achieve the results I'm expecting?  Thanks!

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm accessing this variable in nose unit tests.  This is in Python 2.7.

---

UPDATE: Here's some standalone code that better illustrates what's going on.  It does in fact look like it is related to nose in some way:

```
import nose, os, sys, time

timestamp = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y.%I_%M_%S_%p')
base_directory = "C:\\Users\\Ben\\Desktop\\report_" + timestamp + "\\"
logs_directory = base_directory + "logs\\"

def test_me():
    print base_directory
    print logs_directory

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.makedirs(base_directory)
    os.makedirs(logs_directory)
    print base_directory
    print logs_directory

    time.sleep(5)

    #Without the nocapture argument, nose will internally log all
    #stdout output, and will not output anything to the console.
    argv = (sys.argv[:])
    argv.insert(1, "--nocapture")
    nose.main(argv=argv)  #This will run test_me()
```

And here's the output:

```
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\report_02-13-2015.04_27_32_PM\
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\report_02-13-2015.04_27_32_PM\logs\
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\report_02-13-2015.04_27_37_PM\
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\report_02-13-2015.04_27_37_PM\logs\
```

I was expecting:

```
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\report_02-13-2015.04_27_32_PM\
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\report_02-13-2015.04_27_32_PM\logs\
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\report_02-13-2015.04_27_32_PM\
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\report_02-13-2015.04_27_32_PM\logs\
```

What's going on?  Why is nose re-evaluating strings that have already been initialized?  How do I rewrite my code so that it does what I was expecting?  Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely not normal behaviour. You are not calling the function twice by any chance?

Comment: No, I am not.  These are the only places where the two directory variables are set in the code.  The only caveat here is that I am accessing the logs_directory variable from a nose unit test (the variables are initialized before the unit test is ran).  I'm not sure if there's some sort of artifact in nose or maybe my project setup that is causing this issue to happen. I am very new to nose testing in Python.

Comment: strings are immutable in Python. `base_directory` won't change unless you assign it a new string. Unrelated: you could use `time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y.%I_%M_%S_%p')` if you don't use directives that are supported only by datetime module. Use a regular `python` interpreter to run your script. If the problem persists then [provide the shortest program that demonstrates it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @benjammin, it may well be related to however you are using nose in pydev  as there is no way the string is updating itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

timestamp = time.strftime('%S')

def test_me():
    print('test_me ' + timestamp)
    assert 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose # $ pip install nose
    print('main ' + timestamp)
    time.sleep(3)
    nose.main()
```

`print('main ' + timestamp)` and `print('test_me ' + timestamp)` show different results.

`nose` imports the module internally after the sleep and therefore `timestamp` is different: there are actually two objects `__main__.timestamp` and `module_name.timestamp`.

The module should not have a variable global state if it is both run as a script and can be imported. See [Executing the main module twice](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#executing-the-main-module-twice).

Here's an example without `nose`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Execute main module twice."""
import time

timestamp = time.strftime('%S')

def print_timestamp(prefix):
    print(prefix + timestamp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_timestamp('main')
    time.sleep(3)
    import test_exec_main_twice
    test_exec_main_twice.print_timestamp('module')
```

Save it to `test_exec_main_twice.py` file and run.

Comment: Got it.  I had no idea nose was reimporting the module behind the scenes.  I'll refactor my code so that I avoid this awful double import.  Thank-you!

Comment: @benjammin: `nose` have to import tests if they are in other modules (what `nosetests` does) but I'm not sure whether it is a bug that it reimports the module that runs `nose.main()`. A simple workaround: don't put tests into the script with `nose.main()` in it.